# Mathematica: computing a difficult integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic

I am trying to compute the following integral:

```
Integrate[Exp[Sum[-((cw λ - b[i])^2/(2 σ^2)), {i, 1, n}]], {cw, 0, 1}]
```

And currently *Mathematica* outputs

> ```
> (Sqrt[π/2] σ (Erf[(Sqrt[n] (λ - b[i]))/(Sqrt[2] σ)] + 
>      Erf[(Sqrt[n] b[i])/(Sqrt[2] σ)]))/(Sqrt[n] λ)
> ```

Which is not only blatantly incorrect (there can be no dependence on `i` for example), but also has little connection with my input. If I replace `n` with an integer in the first expression, the output is the correct result for the integration, but I want the general result with `n` summands. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** I am willing to make assumptions, such as that `λ`, `σ` and all `b[i]`'s are real. Nonetheless, that does not seem to matter here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but I can't find it. Anyone?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this particular case *Mathematica* for some reason considers `b[i]` as a constant. Compare:

```
Integrate[Exp[Sum[-((cw λ - b)^2/(2 σ^2)), {i, 1, n}]], {cw, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> (Sqrt[π/2] σ (Erf[(b Sqrt[n])/(Sqrt[2] σ)]-Erf[(Sqrt[n] (b-λ))/(Sqrt[2] σ)]))/(Sqrt[n] λ)
> ```

A possible workaround consists in the manually expanding the sum

```
Integrate[Exp[(-n cw^2 λ^2 + 2 cw λ Sum[b[i], {i, 1, n}] - 
  Sum[b[i]^2, {i, 1, n}])/(2 σ^2)], {cw, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

There is another example of the strange behavior of the sum of `b[i]`

```
Sum[cw b[i], {i, 1, n}] - cw Sum[b[i], {i, 1, n}]
```

[image]

It is not simplified to 0 (even with `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`).

Comment: I have expanded the sum already, but this is quite a quirk...

Comment: Would you not consider this a bug ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yes, it looks like a bug. I usually look for my own mistakes before considering something as a bug.